# Python Beautifulsoup not finding regular expression

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, attributeerror, nonetype

This has been bugging me for a while now, I cannot use regular expressions to find a string with Beautifulsoup, and I have no idea why.

This is the line I'm having troubles with:

```
data = soup.find(text=re.compile('Överförda data (skickade/mottagna)
```

Here is the whole code if needed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import re
import urllib2

# Fetch URL
url = 'http://192.168.1.254/cgi/b/bb/?be=0&l0=1&l1=-1'
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header('Accept-Encoding', 'utf-8')

# Response has UTF-8 charset header,
# and HTML body which is UTF-8 encoded
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response)

time = soup.find(text="Aktiv tid:").findNext('td').contents[0]
data = soup.find(text=re.compile('Överförda data (skickade/mottagna) [GB/GB]:')).findNext('td').contents[0] # complains about this line

f=open('/var/www/log.txt', 'a')
print(time + ";" + data,file=f)
f.close()
```

Whenever I run it, an error of type AttributeError occurs saying 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findNext'

Because my string can be either:

- Överförda data (skickade/mottagna) GB/GB:
- Överförda data (skickade/mottagna) [MB/MB]:

so I need to use regular expressions to see wheter it matches either of these.

Thank you in advance!

(**EDIT**: I now changed my code (see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855025/python-beautifulsoup-not-finding-regular-expression/25855080#25855080) below) but it is still giving me the same error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import re
import urllib2

# Fetch URL
url = 'http://192.168.1.254/cgi/b/bb/?be=0&l0=1&l1=-1'
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header('Accept-Encoding', 'utf-8')

# Response has UTF-8 charset header,
# and HTML body which is UTF-8 encoded
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response)

time = soup.find(text="Aktiv tid:").findNext('td').contents[0]
data = soup.find(text=re.compile(re.escape(u'Överförda data (skickade/mottagna) [GB/GB]:'))).findNext('td').contents[0]

f=open('/var/www/log.txt', 'a')
print(time + ";" + data,file=f)
f.close()
```

Here is the relevant part of the [HTML file](http://pastebin.com/AY5B01wx):

```
<table width='100%' class='datatable' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td width='30px'>
    </td>
    <td width='220px'>
    </td>
    <td width='50px'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height='7' colspan='4'>
      <img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width='170'>
      Aktiv tid: <!--This is a string I will search for.-->
    </td>
    <td colspan='3'>
      1 dag, 17:03:46 <!--This is a piece of information I need to obtain.-->
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height='7' colspan='4'>
      <img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width='170'>
      Bandbredd (upp/ned) [kbps/kbps]:
    </td>
    <td colspan='3'>
      1.058 / 21.373
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height='7' colspan='4'>
      <img src='/images/spacer.gif' width='1' height='7' border='0' alt=''>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width='170'>
      Överförda data (skickade/mottagna) [GB/GB]: <!--This is another string I will search for.-->
    </td>
    <td colspan='3'>
      1,67 / 42,95 <!--This is another piece of information I need to obtain.-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BeautifulSoup operates on *unicode* strings, but you passed in a bytestring regex instead. Use a Unicode literal for your expression:

```
re.compile(re.escape(u'Överförda data (skickade/mottagna) [GB/GB]:'))
```

I also used `re.escape()` to escape the meta characters (parentheses and square brackets) from being interpreted as regular expression info.

The UTF-8 encoding of `Ö` and `ö` will only match the exact *byte sequence*:

```
>>> 'Överförda'
'\xc3\x96verf\xc3\xb6rda'
>>> u'Överförda'
u'\xd6verf\xf6rda'
>>> print u'Överförda'
Överförda
>>> import re
>>> re.search('Överförda', u'Överförda data (skickade/mottagna) [GB/GB]')
>>> re.search(u'Överförda', u'Överförda data (skickade/mottagna) [GB/GB]')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x107d47ed0>
```

This does require that you make a proper source code encoding declaration at the top of your file, see [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

Comment: Thank you, but I did make a encoding declaration as utf-8, and used the Unicode literal like this: `re.compile(u'Överförda data (skickade/mottagna) [GB/GB]:')` but it still gave me the same result.

Comment: @Linus: Ah, you need to escape meta characters in your expression too.

Comment: Still I'm having problems with the same error message (see my edit).

Comment: @Linus: can you provide us with any sample input at all?

Comment: I have added my HTML file now and the relevant part.

Comment: Very strange, because for me it still generates the same error. Perhaps I have an outdated version of python?

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets and parentheses are special in regular expressions. You need to escape them with a backslash if you want to match those literal characters (vs. defining capture groups, character classes, etc).

Comment: Do I need to escape forward slash aswell?

Comment: No, forward slash is ok. I'm using Python 2.6.6 on Linux, and this works for me: `>>> import re;pat=re.compile(u'Överförda');m=pat.search(u'Överförda data (skickade/mottagna) [GB/GB]');print m.group()
Överförda`